# write a function with no arguments to compute a 3 digit number bac

Tags: python, function

So I need help in this question. Basically I need t write a function which takes no arguments and returns a 3 digit number back where aa+bb+cc=bac. I have so far this..

```
dec_digits = range(1,10)
for (a,b,c) in permutations(decimal_digits,3):
    aa = 11*a
    bb = 11*b
    cc = 11*c
    bac = 100*b + 10*a + c
    if bac == aa + bb + cc:
        print(bac, "is bac in puzzle aa+bb+cc=bac")
```

this works but isn't a function so I'm unsure how to change it do a function..

Comment: just put a `def my_func():` on top and indent the whole thing. Your algorithm and requirements are a bit weird to be honest though..

Comment: I was thinking that but then id still have arguments within my code..

Comment: The empty parenthesis on the function declaration line means that no arguments are expected from the function; and subsequently none are passed. Of course the function itself will use variables but that is something entirely different and normal

Comment: if theres no arguments in the function declaration parenthesis then none are needed

Comment: so even though my program has aa = .. etc the function isn't taking any arguments ? complete beginner here trying to work my way through some online questions :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

To create a function in python all you have to do is define it using the def keyword. So your code will be like this:

```
def test():
    dec_digits = range(1,10)
    for (a,b,c) in permutations(decimal_digits,3):
        aa = 11*a
        bb = 11*b
        cc = 11*c
        bac = 100*b + 10*a + c
        if bac == aa + bb + cc:
            print(bac, "is bac in puzzle aa+bb+cc=bac")
```

If you need to return the value just replace the print statement with `return bac` and if you ever need to add parameters just place them inside of the parentheses near the name of the function. To call on a function type its name and add brackets, for example:

```
test()
```